# Java for loop getting StringIndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: java, for-loop, indexoutofboundsexception

so I'm trying to change one string (guilty) into a scrambled version of the same string.  The only thing not random is that any double letters have to be put together.  So if I had the string "pharmacy" it would have to be something like "mraacpyh".  I thought I figured it out, but now I'm getting a StringIndexOutOfBoundsException. Can anyone shine some light on what I'm doing wrong?

```
   String guilty = "";
   String scramble = "";
   if (killer == 0)
     guilty = "pharmacy";
   if (killer == 1)
     guilty = "closet";
   if (killer == 2)
     guilty = "newspaper";
   if (killer == 3)
     guilty = "dollar";
   if (killer == 4)
     guilty = "college";

   while (!guilty.equals("")){
      int i = r.nextInt(guilty.length());
      for (int j = 0; j < guilty.length()-guilty.replace(guilty.substring(i, i+1), "").length(); i++){
      scramble = scramble + guilty.substring(i, i+1);
      }
      guilty = guilty.replace(guilty.substring(i, i+1), "");
      System.out.println(scramble);
      System.out.println(guilty);
   }
```

Comment: You should change you while loop to an if statement. `if(!guilty.equals("")){`

Comment: Your code is quite incomplete. We don't know what killer is doing right from the start. Paste your full code.

Comment: @progyammer Probably killing, since this part of the code is trying to find the guilty party.

Answer (score 0):

```
int i = r.nextInt(guilty.length());
```

If guilty is 'APPLE' i is 5. index of the last char 'E' is 4! (1st char's index is 0) 
Problem is here:

```
guilty.replace(guilty.substring(i, i+1), "")
```

if you increase variable i, it will be higher then the maximum index of your string. i is the maximum index of your string.

Otherwise, Shuffling a String:

```
import org.apache.commons.lang3.ArrayUtils; //ver.3.6
...
String s = "apple";
char[] chars = s.toCharArray();
ArrayUtils.shuffle(chars);
System.out.print(String.valueOf(chars));
```